# Kinect can't be connected to my netbook

Tags: openni-kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Ubuntu10.10.  Following the diamondback installation instruction, I installed the ros-diamondback-turtlebot-robot,and finished turtlebot setup,networking setup,environment setup. There was nothing wrong, and I thought it's OK to connect the kinect.

However, when I tried roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch,it presented that

```
[ INFO] [1320732062.736897541]: [/openni_node1] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

Then I installed openni_kinect according to http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect, I got the same result.The light of kinect was twinkling,It didn't work, either.
I sincerely wish someone could give me some suggestions,thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11849/kinect-can%27t-be-connected-to-my-netbook/) by [LG_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1330/lg_turtlebot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) on 2011-11-07**:
Please edit your question and copy-paste in the output from openni_node.launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please follow the [TurtleBot Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot)  you need to make sure the breakers are turned on for the Kinect.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LG_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1330/lg_turtlebot/) on 2011-11-23**:
I have solved my problems,thank you all the same.